# Object #<Object> has no method 'getStore' on the app init

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, workflow

I'm trying to get Store in the view on the init of the applicatoin, however the console tells me: `Object #<Object> has no method 'getStore'`

I'm wondering how would you get a store in this sequence:

1. Initialise app
2. Get user GPS location
3. Create a store
4. Display view with the store

```
    init: function () { 
        this.callParent();
        console.log("controller init");
    },
    launch: function () {
        this.getApplicationSettings();
        this.getApplicationRegionalisation();
        Ext.getStore("appSettings").setValue("region", "Melbourne");

        var store = Ext.create("APN.store.Locations");
        var geo = Ext.create('Ext.util.Geolocation', {
            autoUpdate: false,
            listeners: {
                locationupdate: function(geo) {
                    var location = store.getClosestLocation(geo.getLatitude(), geo.getLongitude());
                    Ext.getStore("appSettings").setValue("region", location.get("location"));
                },
                locationerror: function(geo, bTimeout, bPermissionDenied, bLocationUnavailable, message) {
                }
            }
        });
```

And then in the view I would like to call something like this, correct me if I'm doing a stupid thing:

```
    requires: [
        'APN.store.AppSettings'
    ],
..... omitted stuff

// in items:
        items: [
            {
                itemId: 'nav_home',
        id: 'homeView',
                group: '',
                title: "Home",
                layout: 'vbox',
                slideButton: { selector: 'toolbar' },
                settingsButton: { selector: 'toolbar' },
                items: [{
                   xtype: 'articlelist',
                   id: 'latestNews',
                   category: 'Latest',
                   feedUrlName: 
// here is the place where it bugs out!
Ext.getStore("appSettings").getValue(Ext.getStore("appSettings").getValue("region").get("menuItems").home.url,
               }
                ],
            },
```

Comment: at which line you are getting errors?

Comment: where the it says `// here is the place where it bugs out`

So my understanding when the application loads all files and `compiles` `interprets` them and sees that Ext.Store is not initialized, then it loads controller `init` method and controller `launch` method where the store is initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you are creating the view, you can create the store before that and set store to the view explicitly so that when initialize function is executed it will get `this.config.store`. To get GPS location on app initialization, you can get location in Launch function of `Ext.application` before even creating the store and view. If you want to create view only after store data is loaded, you should create view in load callback of store.

I hope this is what you were looking for, if not please add some code to your question so that we can comment on specifics.

Comment: just updated, actually you gave me a bit of understanding... but anyway still searching